# Alternative keyboard shortcuts to Resharper's "Open by filename" or "Open by typename"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Resharper has some commands I just can't live without (keybindings are given for the Visual Studio template):

- Open by filename (Ctrl+Shift+T)
- Locate in solution explorer (alt-shift-T, useful only when solution explorer is configured not to track the current file already)

Does visual studio have alternatives to these that don't require Resharper?  I know VS2010 adds the "Edit.NavigateTo" command (Ctrl+,) but it is slow and shows every useless symbol that might be what you want (too noisy).

Is anything similar offered by other perhaps free addons?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [Solution Navigator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/20/solution-navigator-blog-post.aspx) feature that is bundled with the free [Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) extension. It appears to have more powerful support for searching for files and symbols all combined within the Solution Explorer.